# Is it possible to make specific letter in a word to be a custom font in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make specific letter to have a custom font or style in Flutter, is it possible to do that? I only saw tutorial on how to make specific word in Flutter to have custom style by using RichText. Is there anyway to make a specific letter instead of a word?

for example

**n** elephant

In this case the letter A will have a custom font but the letter n does not.

Comment: What did the tutorial say?

Comment: Well the tutorial only talked about by using richtext you can make specific word to be differ from other but what I want is only specific letter instead of word.

Comment: The solution is going to be pretty similar, so again: what did the tutorial say?

Answer (score 0):

The `text` parameter in a `TextSpan` can be omitted. So for what you want, you can just use the `children` parameter and have the first child be a single character.

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'L',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      const TextSpan(text: 'ike this?')
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
Text.rich(
      TextSpan(text: 'This is textspan ', children: <InlineSpan>[
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Widget in flutter',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )
      ]),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it any way you want :D

```
String myString = "Helloooo";
String specialChar = "o";

RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        children: myString.characters.map((e) {
  return TextSpan(
    text: e,
    style: e == specialChar
        ? TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40)
        : TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 50),
  );
}).toList()));
```